# Apache2 Virtualhost config for redmine on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, redmine, virtualhost

I just installed redmine on my ubuntu server 10.04. Redmine is installed correctly because when I start it as standalone I can access it via `mydomain.com:3000`.

Redmine is located in `/usr/share/redmine`.

Now I want to access redmine from a subdomain, e.g. `redmine.mysite.com`. So I added a redmine file to the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and `/etc/apache2/sites-avialable`  folder with following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName redmine.mysite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public

        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_error
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_access combined

        <Directory /usr/share/redmine/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I execute following commands

```
sudo a2ensite redmine
sudo service apache2 reload
```

But my subdomains still shows the default empty plesk page. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plesk needs to know that you have reconfigured the domain... try:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=mysite.com
```

then you want to restart [i.e. service apache2 stop ; service apache2 start] the apache service

check the docs for the full use of websrvmng

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/websrvmng --help
```

-sean

Comment: tbanks, but I still get the default plesk page, apache seems to completelly ignore my config

Comment: sorry - I should have looked closer, your redmine app is listening on port 3000 & apache 80 .. you have been through this:http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_configure_Apache_to_run_Redmine